# Can't browse the internet nor ping a host, but dig works

Tags: networking, dns

I am not able to browse any websites. Please take a look at the following error:

```
karthick@karthick:~$ ping www.google.com                         
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

### Update

```
karthick@karthick:~$ dig www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.1-P2 <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26402
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     238583  IN  CNAME   www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com.   97  IN  A   74.125.236.50
www.l.google.com.   97  IN  A   74.125.236.48
www.l.google.com.   97  IN  A   74.125.236.52
www.l.google.com.   97  IN  A   74.125.236.49
www.l.google.com.   97  IN  A   74.125.236.51

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     146866  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     146866  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.com.     146866  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     146866  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.google.com.     317814  IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns1.google.com.     317814  IN  A   216.239.32.10
ns3.google.com.     317814  IN  A   216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.     317814  IN  A   216.239.38.10

;; Query time: 5 msec
;; SERVER: 172.29.39.212#53(172.29.39.212)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug  3 15:30:38 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 268
```

## Output:

```
karthick@karthick:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:30:5b:c4:fd:dc  
inet addr:172.29.XX.XX  Bcast:172.29.XX.XXX  Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::be30:5bff:fec4:fddc/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:1757954 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:1422948 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:1329324192 (1.3 GB)  TX bytes:1231317787 (1.2 GB)
Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
RX packets:10528 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:10528 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
RX bytes:768164 (768.1 KB)  TX bytes:768164 (768.1 KB)

karthick@karthick:~$ sudo iptables -nvL
[sudo] password for karthick: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source           destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source           destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: How are you trying to connect to your ISP? Wireless/Ethernet (Cable) or modem. In order to help with this problem we will need some more information from you.

Comment: This seems to be a networking problem.

Comment: paste this command's output: ifconfig

Comment: Is it significant that there is no "base address" on the Interrupt line?

Comment: Do you use any firewall? Try paste the output of `iptables -nvL`

Comment: @karthick87 - has any hardware changed between your PC and the internet e.g. your router?  Is there an onward hop between your router and a separate modem?  if there is - maybe you need to "clone your PC mac address" in your router config to allow your modem to see your actual mac-address

Comment: What is in your `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, especially on the line that starts with `hosts:`? You should have `dns` somewhere on that line.

Comment: what is the output of `sudo route -n`?

Comment: @taneli yes i have found the problem is i dont have dns on that line. After adding it the problem got resolved. Pls write it as an answer. So that i will mark this is solved. Thankyou :)

Comment: Excellent that you got it sorted out! Seems that the question is solved, so I guess my answer is not needed any more.

Comment: Why did `dig` work?

Comment: @tanel As this turns out to solve the problem, please post it as an answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Stefano Palazzo I added the answer now, although karthick87's own answer is clearer than mine ...

Comment: @Scaine `dig`, `host` and `nslookup` do not use the name service switch (as they don't need to consider other name service mechanisms than DNS). Most other software uses it. It is part of libc, and `man nsswitch.conf` on the command line will give you rationale and overview.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found that  the problem lies in this file `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. In that file dns entry was missed. After adding that entry i am able to browse the sites.

[image: NSSWITCH]

Comment: @OXwivi: taneli answered the question almost a day after karthick87 had answered it him self.

Comment: @binW, thanks for pointing it out, I did not notice the time gap. It's a shame the bounty's going to waste though...

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `dns` to `/etc/nsswitch.conf` on the line that starts with `hosts:`. For example, mine has

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

which I think is the default in natty.

It would be good to know if your setup was broken by some software, as it is highly uncommon (and difficult to diagnose) if the name service switch facility is not using the default settings.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you've got connectivity to the Internet (dig works ok, DNS replies are good), so perhaps it's a higher-level issue, like proxy setup.

So, have you checked your system's proxy settings?

Comment: Perhaps run a wget to test http directly?

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a DNS issue.

Run `dig example.com` to check such a DNS query. If it times out or fails, the configured DNS server is broken. Try setting an alternative DNS server by adding the next line to `/etc/resolv.conf` (replacing other `nameserver` entries):

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

This nameserver is from Google, but can be set to any valid DNS server.

Comment: I have tried but still i am getting the same error..

Comment: can you post the contents of your resolve.conf file?

Comment: [OpenDNS](http://opendns.com) can be used for DNS resolution as well.

Answer (score 1):

did you notice this

```
RX bytes:1329324192 (1.3 GB)  TX bytes:1231317787 (1.2 GB)
```

you are receiving 1.3 Giga Bytes and transmitting 1.2 Giga Bytes. I have been listening to a radio program through the web browser for almost two hours and I have only Received (RX) 888.8 MB and transmitted (TX) 22.7 MB. Something is using your network connection and this could be what is blocking your access. You do not say what OS you are using. You may now be the proud owner of a zombie machine.

Are you using a torrent? Have you given it too much bandwidth?

Comment: That depends on how long you have your computer running, I get my share of a couple GB if I update some Linux VMs. The sending is still odd, though.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off all applications (Firefox, Thunderbird, etc).

Then enter these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo -s  <enter your password>
date
tcpdump -qtn port 53 & host www.google.com
Ctrl-c (2 keys on the keyboard)
```

The last 2 commands are for stopping the tcpdump command.

Post the output back into your question as an edit (assuming you find a way to do so without a working internet connection - perhaps a USB key to transfer the text log to a PC with internet?).

Answer (score 0):

I've recently [had this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/298610/why-are-microsoft-based-programs-unable-to-resolve-host-names) on Windows where I had DNS but no Ping, there are two possibilities:

1. You are using a proxy that is not correctly working, get rid of the proxy or fix it.
2. There is something broken in the network chain; which means that you have to rebuild it from scratch, if you don't want to get your hands dirty with cleaning and reinstalling network drivers and programs you might as well take a back-up and reinstall Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

It must be an ISP problem, or the local modem/router/switch plays with you. Restart your machine, modem and all network affected devices.

(Otherwise, can you ping Google by IP: 74.125.236.50 ?)

Answer (score 0):

You've masked off your IP address as 172.29.XX.YY, but since your subnet mask is 255.255.**255**.0, you need to make sure that the third octect (the xx, not the yy), is the same as your default router.  If not, then you'll only see PCs on the same subnet as you (172.29.xx).  If your DNS server is on the same subnet as yours, this would explain why nothing, except it, is working.

Answer (score 0):

One way to rule out the browser being the problem would be to run:

telnet google.com 80

from a Terminal prompt. If it works you should have two lines that say:
**Connected to google.com
Escape character is  '^]..**

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem today, where all network setting where correct, but I could only ping and reach local machines.

I checked the above file and had the DNS entry but noticed I missed the `mdns4` entry . After adding the `mdns4` all is OK. 
Mentioning this  in case some one else runs into same problem

Answer (score 0):

I realize this has been solved, but I had the same symptom and the solution had to do with the default network interface card that is used by the program in question.

N.B. All linux machines (Ubuntu 15.10). DNS is bind9 running on Ubuntu 15.10 as well.

I set up a DNS server on a LAN to which the connected machines were using their second or third network interface card (i.e. each machine had several network interface cards connected to different networks) e.g. (for any given machine on the network in question):

1. Interface 1: enp0s3 connected to some network with no DNS configured
2. Interface 2: enp0s8 connected to the network with the new DNS
3. Interface 3: enp0s9 connected to some network with no DNS configured

Dig's behaviour appears to indicate that it iteratively goes through all the interfaces until it gets a response, whereas ping just tries the first interface then stops/gives up.

After "downing" the first interface with:

```
ifconfig enp0s3 down
```

ping then started using the DNS on enp0s8

Hope this helps anyone who might still be trying to figure it out.